# Android NFC, app minimizing on pages without NFC

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

Having a few problems with a system I have created.

On certain pages such as the log in screen, I accept NFC card swipes to read the ID and log the user in

However when a user scans the card on a page that doesn't have the NFC coded into it, the android device auto minimizes my application and brings up a list of programs to open using the NFC cards.  I want it just to do nothing and keep my application in the front screen.

is there anyway I can solve this without coding NFC into every page and checking for scans but doing nothing on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this without activating the NFC foreground dispatch for every activity and ignoring any received events.

What you can do, is to subclass Android's `Activity` class and add the foreground dispatch functionality to that class. Then, for every activity that should block NFC events (or actually for every activity in your app), you extend that sublcass instead of extending the normal Android `Activity` class.